# How do i install magento2 in mac?

Tags: magento2, php, database

I have followed these steps, [https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-on-macbook/[1]](https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-on-macbook/%5B1%5D) and installed magento2, and when i updgrade and deploy bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f , like this i am getting error.[image]

Comment: please tell us more about your setup? whats the return of php -v or composer -V?
which version of magento have you installed? why you need to run this command with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion is to build Magento through `docker`

For example: https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP version < 8.1 but your Magento version (>=2.4.4) requires PHP 8.1. To resolve your issue, switch your PHP version to 8.1.

In your case, you are using MAMP. So open MAMP setting to select PHP version 8.1. In case after doing that from MAMP setting, the issue still persists, which means you didn't switch to PHP 8.1 successfully. Search google for change PHP version in MAMP or try the solution on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325159/changing-php-version-in-mamp